# How do you work backward and get the button from other people code

Tags: applescript, automator

Let say this was the code provided? How do I get to see the “list 1 of group 2 of group 1 of group 1)? I understand that you would need to use the accessibility inspector but I have no clue how to do it. Hope someone can help out. Thank you!!!

```
    tell application "System Events"
    --mission control starten
    tell application "Mission Control" to launch
    delay 0.25
    tell process "Dock"
        set countSpaces to count buttons of list 1 of group 2 of group 1 of group 1
        --new space
        click button 1 of group 2 of group 1 of group 1
        --switch to new space
        repeat until (count buttons of list 1 of group 2 of group 1 of group 1) = (countSpaces + 1)
        end repeat
        click button (countSpaces + 1) of list 1 of group 2 of group 1 of group 1
    end tell
    delay 0.25
    tell application "Calendar" to launch
    tell application "Reminders" to launch
end tell
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question yet. Also, what programming language is this?

Comment: What do you mean by _"see"_ ?  The object reference is to a UI element on your screen, so you can see it just by looking at your screen.  It's your dock, or rather the icons in your dock.

Comment: Sorry for not wording my question well. 

The above code was provided as a solution to create a new desktop on a MacBook and open the Calendar and Reminder app. I want to modify the code in the future, but when I try to do so, I don't know what does the the code" list 1 of group 2 of group 1 of group 1" refer to. 

From what I understand, the code above usually refers to a UI element  that can be identified with the hierarchy in accessibility inspector. or  ( using the Watch me do function in automator).

However,someone wrote the above code, I have no idea , where can I find this button

Comment: @RaymondChen

Sorry for not being clear, I will try to paraphrase.

Let say this was the code provided. How do I get to see the physical button on my computer which is represented by the code “list 1 of group 2 of group 1 of group 1)? This is written with apple script

Comment: In this situation the Accessibility Inspector will get switched out by Mission Control, but you can use a script to explore manually - start at the base UI element and look at the elements it contains, choose one, look at what it contains, and so on.  If you are just wondering what the list is, it is a list of the buttons in the Spaces Bar (of Mission Control).

Comment: Thank you red menace(: